# Unity3D new ui Mask behaves wrong with runtime generated Texture2D

Tags: unity-game-engine, mask, texture2d

In my project I have a texture2D that is generated in runtime, and a texture2D, that is stored in my project, not generated in runtime, both under a mask. When I try to increase their scale and move them with scroll rect under this mask, it behaves strange on some devices. The runtime-generated texture becomes partially invisible, though the other one works as needed.

I've already tried to change texture formats, filter modes and all the properties that texture has at all. I've configured runtime generated texture to have exactly the same properties as the preloaded one that works fine. But it still behaves the same.

In my code I load all textures from a specified folder with Resources.LoadAll(), and then I change every visible pixel of every loaded texture to white color.
maskTexturesObj is an Object[] array resulted by Resources.LoadAll() method.
Here is the code where I create my texture:

```
        processedTexture = maskTexturesObj[i] as Texture2D;
        for (int y = 0; y < processedTexture.height; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < processedTexture.width; x++)
            {
                if (processedTexture.GetPixel(x, y).a > 0)
                    processedTexture.SetPixel(x, y, Color.white);
            }
        }
        processedTexture.Apply();
        lessonPartImage.sprite = Sprite.Create(processedTexture, new Rect(0, 0, processedTexture.width, processedTexture.height), Vector2.zero);
```

The result is on the screenshot:
[image]

And here is what it is supposed to be: [image]

Comment: It could be a problem with the Mipmaps of the generated texture.

Comment: @AntiHeadshot I tried to turn off the mipMap generation, it didn't help, unfortunately.